# Simple cpp program runs under standard GNU/Linux, but not MacOS M1

Tags: linux, macos, g++

I've been writing a simple program under GNU/Linux (Debian) for quite some time, and recently I wanted to try it out under macOS running on the new M1 chip. However, g++ refuses to run it and throws *a lot* of errors. g++ under Debian has no problem at all. AFAIK, all dependencies have been satisfied, so I don't get why it wouldn't run.

An excerpt of my code (two methods; there's more, but this is as much as I can share):

```cpp
    #include <unistd.h>
    
    uint64_t constexpr mix(char m, uint64_t s)
    {
        return ((s << 7) + ~(s >> 3)) + ~m;
    }
    
    uint64_t constexpr hashIt(const char* m)
    {
        return (*m) ? mix(*m, hashIt(m + 1)) : 0;
    }
```

g++ returns the following:

```
main2.cpp:3:19: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
uint64_t constexpr mix(char m, uint64_t s)
                  ^
                  ;
1 error generated.
```

It runs flawlessly under Debian and likely any other distro.

Thanks for any answer!

EDIT: I ran `brew install gcc` and successfully installed the package. However, it isn't anywhere in the usual directories (`/usr/local/bin, /usr/local/Cellar`.)

Comment: @Kusalananda One more thing. I've found that Homebrew (at least 3.2.2 on macOS) saves its data into `/opt/homebrew/` and binaries into `/opt/homebrew/bin/`, as opposed to `/usr/local/bin/`. Just wanted to point that out for future reference if anyone is looking for this.

Comment: Homebrew uses `/opt/homebrew` for "Apple Silicon", but `/usr/local` for macOS Intel (and `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew` on Linux).  This is documented in the [installation instructions for Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation).

Comment: Ahh, okay. Good to know. Ah, this new Silicon just complicates things ... :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When installing the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) on macOS through the Homebrew package manager using `brew install gcc`, the `g++` executable will be called `g++-11`, where `11` will be some number corresponding to the most recent release of GCC.

This is to allow multiple versions of GCC to be installed at the same time, e.g. through `brew install gcc@9` to install release 9, and also to allow `g++` without a number to remain Apple's alias for `clang++`.

So, in your case, install the `gcc` package and use `g++-11` as your C++ compile, the `clang++` compiler on macOS does not support your code.